# Codenameone app with banner ads - outdated version reported

Tags: android, codenameone, ads, banner

I made a new version of my cn1-app, and I am trying to publish it on Google Play console.
After uploading the aab file, the following error was reported:

> Error: The developer of Google Mobile Ads (GMA) SDK (com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads) has reported version 12.0.1 as outdated. You must upgrade to a newer version (19.4.0+) before you can publish a new release to production.

My new version contains banner ads, while the previous version had interstitial ads (and it contained: AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib). A similar warning was reported last time (when I published the last version). But now it is not a warning but an error. I use: cn1 + netbeans + maven. I don't use any more AdmobFullScreen.cn1lib. I deleted from one pom.xml file (common - folder) the admobfullscreen - dependency. I also deleted all folders of the type: 'admob-fullscreen-' in the local maven repository. Is it possible that there are still some remains of the admobfullscreen library, or are the banner ads the cause of the above problem ? Can other people use banner ads, within a cn1 project, without any problems ?

Some build hints are:

> android.playService.ads=true
> android.googleAdUnitId=ca-app-pub-something   codename1.arg.android.licenseKey=something
> codename1.arg.android.xapplication=<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
> codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly set the play services version as explained in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/11cmkp9/changes_to_android_play_services_versions/). Although I don't think you'll need it.

In your case I think just using the following build hint should be enough:

```
android.playService.ads=true
```

If this still doesn't work you can also add:

```
android.decouplePlayServiceVersions=true
android.playService.ads=18.0.1
```

Original Answer Below:

Including your `android.` build hints would help in diagnosing this. Also it's unclear how you include the banner ads.

My understanding is that you don't use Googles ads anymore and just want to remove this entirely. I'm assuming that you have no definitions regarding the play services inclusion so I suggest adding at least one explicit hint to disable the default fallback. Specifically, add the build hint: `android.playService.ads=false`.

Comment: I do use Google ads. I include the banner ads by adding a build hint: android.googleAdUnitId=ca-app-pub-something. Some build hints are added in the above post. The app works fine if I install the apk file on my smartphone and the banner ads work too. But it was rejected on the Google console. In the meantime, I created a new app without the banner ads (to see where is the problem) and uploaded the app on the Google console, and no error was reported. So it seems to me that the banner ads are the cause of the problem. Is it possible that they use some  outdated library?

Comment: I edited my answer to address the issue

Comment: I did used the first build hint: 'android.playService.ads=true' (see my post). I will try to include the second build hint: 'android.playServicesVersion.ads=18.0.1'. One question: in the post that you mentioned, the name of this build hint is different: instead of 'android.playServicesVersion.ads' it is: 'android.playService.XXX' (E.g. `android.playService.maps=18.0.1` ). I believe that the build hint that you stated is correct?
Another question: in the report error (in my post), it states: "You must upgrade to a newer version (19.4.0+)". So should I use '18.0.1' or '19.4.0' ?

Comment: You're right, my hint was incorrect. I included a revised hint and I think it might be necessary to define `android.decouplePlayServiceVersions=true`